# Remove NaN word from javascript when deselecting checkbox

Tags: javascript

Friends, the word NaN appears when deselecting.

If my code is wrong could you tell me where it is wrong?

I don't know much about programming, I tried reading some other code but without success.

How can I fix this?

Total sum of the selected numbers is OK

Total marked is Ok

Numbers that were chosen where is the problem.

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp01.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E1" value="1" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp02.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E2" value="2" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp03.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E3" value="3" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp04.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E4" value="4" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp05.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E5" value="5" /></br>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp06.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E6" value="6" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp07.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E7" value="7" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp08.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E8" value="8" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp09.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E9" value="9" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp10.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E10" value="10" /><br/>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp11.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E11" value="11" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp12.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E12" value="12" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp13.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E13" value="13" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp14.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E14" value="14" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp15.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E15" value="15" /><br/>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp16.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E16" value="16" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp17.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E17" value="17" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp18.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E18" value="18" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp19.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E19" value="19" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp20.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E20" value="20" /><br/>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp21.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E21" value="21" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp22.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E22" value="22" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp23.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E23" value="23" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp24.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E24" value="24" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp25.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E25" value="25" />
<p id="total">Total sum of the selected:</p>
<p id="total2">Total marked:</p>
<p id="total3">Numbers that were chosen:</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let total = 0; let total2 = 0; let total3 = ""; let total_N = ""; 
[...document.getElementsByClassName('iput')].forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      total += parseInt(e.target.value, 10); total3 += ['\n' + parseInt(e.target.value, 10)];
      total2 += 1; 
    } else {
      total -= parseInt(e.target.value, 10); total_N += total3; total_N -= ['\n' + parseInt(e.target.value, 10)];
      total2 -= 1; total3 += total_N;
    }
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = "Total sum of the selected:: <strong>"+total+"</strong>";
    document.getElementById('total2').innerHTML = "Total marked:: <strong>"+total2+"</strong>";
    document.getElementById('total3').innerHTML = "Numbers that were chosen:<strong>"+total3+"</strong>";

  })

})
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `total3` is a string, and you're trying to add an array to it. Then, once you've done that, you try to subtract another array from it. That's not how any of this works.

Comment: You cannot "subtract" from a string with the `-=` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the line below

```
total3 += ['\n' + parseInt(e.target.value, 10)];
```

`total3` in your code is `string`. It should be added to other string only but you are trying to add an array to it.

I replaced `total3` with name `allNum`. Make `allNum` an empty array `[]`. If you new element is selected then `push()` that to array if element is deselected use `filter()` to remove that number.

```js
let total = 0;
let total2 = 0;
let allNum = []
let total_N = "";
[...document.getElementsByClassName('iput')].forEach(function(item) {
   item.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
      if (e.target.checked) {
         total += parseInt(e.target.value, 10);
         allNum.push(+e.target.value)
         total2 += 1;
      } else {
         total -= parseInt(e.target.value, 10);
         total_N += total3;
         allNum = allNum.filter(x => x !== +e.target.value)
         total2 -= 1;
         total3 += total_N;
      }
      document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = "Total sum of the selected:: <strong>" + total + "</strong>";
      document.getElementById('total2').innerHTML = "Total marked:: <strong>" + total2 + "</strong>";
      document.getElementById('total3').innerHTML = "Numbers that were chosen:<strong>" + allNum.join(' ')+ "</strong>";
   })
})
```

```html
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp01.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E1" value="1" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp02.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E2" value="2" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp03.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E3" value="3" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp04.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E4" value="4" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp05.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E5" value="5" /></br>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp06.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E6" value="6" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp07.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E7" value="7" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp08.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E8" value="8" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp09.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E9" value="9" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp10.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E10" value="10" /><br/>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp11.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E11" value="11" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp12.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E12" value="12" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp13.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E13" value="13" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp14.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E14" value="14" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp15.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E15" value="15" /><br/>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp16.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E16" value="16" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp17.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E17" value="17" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp18.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E18" value="18" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp19.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E19" value="19" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp20.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E20" value="20" /><br/>
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp21.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E21" value="21" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp22.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E22" value="22" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp23.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E23" value="23" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp24.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E24" value="24" />
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp25.<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E25" value="25" />
<p id="total">Total sum of the selected:</p>
<p id="total2">Total marked:</p>
<p id="total3">Numbers that were chosen:</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach is "keep track of changes as they happen", but for something small like this you may have a much easier time with a simple "just recalculate everything" approach.

I'll also take the opportunity to introduce you to `<ol>` for the numbered list, and `display: flex;` or `display: grid;` for layout (instead of `&nbsp;`/`<br>` spam)

Also delegated event handlers, so that you have a single event handler on the container, rather than 25 individual event handlers.

```js
const container = document.getElementById('selections');
const checkboxes = container.querySelectorAll("[type=checkbox]");
const outputs = [
  document.getElementById('total'),
  document.getElementById('total2'),
  document.getElementById('total3')
];

container.addEventListener("change", function() {
  let total = 0, count = 0, selected = [];
  checkboxes.forEach(cb=>{
    if( cb.checked) {
      total += +cb.value;
      count++;
      selected.push(cb.value);
    }
  });
  outputs[0].value = total;
  outputs[1].value = count;
  outputs[2].value = selected.join(", ") || "None";
});
```

```css
#selections {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, auto);
}
```

```html
<ol id="selections">
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="E1" value="1" /></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="E2" value="2" /></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="E3" value="3" /></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="E4" value="4" /></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="E5" value="5" /></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="E6" value="6" /></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="E7" value="7" /></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="E8" value="8" /></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="E9" value="9" /></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="E10" value="10" /></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="E11" value="11" /></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="E12" value="12" /></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="E13" value="13" /></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="E14" value="14" /></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="E15" value="15" /></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="E16" value="16" /></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="E17" value="17" /></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="E18" value="18" /></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="E19" value="19" /></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="E20" value="20" /></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="E21" value="21" /></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="E22" value="22" /></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="E23" value="23" /></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="E24" value="24" /></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="E25" value="25" /></li>
</ol>
<p>Total sum of the selected: <output id="total">0</output></p>
<p>Total marked: <output id="total2">0</output></p>
<p>Numbers that were chosen: <output id="total3">None</output></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

NaN stands for 'not a number'.

I think the confusion comes because you are adding numbers using the '+' sign (which is correct) you are concatenating two strings together using the plus sign (also correct), subtracting two numbers using the - sign (correct), trying to remove a substring from a string (total_N) using the - sign (incorrect).

To remove substrings you need to find out about string.replace(str) and step through each line of your code making sure you understand exactly what each statement is doing.

It's also useful to use the developer tools in your browser and if you are unsure whether a statement is giving you what you expect put a console.log() into the code to check what value it has.